# Stack Exchange is free to use , so how does it earn money?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, business-model

I don't paid for using Stack Exchange communities, so how they make money to support it all?

Comment: Are you asking how Stack Exchange makes money? Or how you can make money while using a Stack Exchange site?

Comment: Yes sorry, I ask how Stack Exchange makes money?

Comment: The question is answered in the duplicate linked to by jonsca. And remember, when a commercial service is free to you, you're not the customer, you're the product.